# How do add data-attributes in scuccess of Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having some Static DOM inside web page. I am trying to dynamically add attributes to some of the element of existing dom and insert at certain location.Here is what I am trying so far.

```
   $.ajax({
         type:"GET",
         async: false,
         url:contextpath+"/phase/data/getData",
         data:postData,
         success: function (msg) {
               // msg ='<div class="row-sml">
                //            <div class="col col-xs-12 text-right plr30 mb8 displayhide">
               //               <button  type="button" class="btn btn-light-grey cus-btn mt10 rephrase-btn" id="submit-problem-phrase-button">Submit</button>
              //              </div>';
                $(msg).find('#submit-problem-phrase-button').attr('data',wikiTopicId);
                $('#insertHere').html(msg);
         },
         error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
             $('.loader02,#overlay-bg,.trans-overlay').hide();
         } 
         });
```

But it is not working

Comment: You need to `append()` the HTML to the DOM - you can't just dump it in the middle of your JS code. As you can see from the syntax highlighting in the question, it causes several issues.

Comment: Try this $(msg).find('#submit-problem-phrase-button').data('wikiTopicId', wikiTopicId) to set and then to get value back like this $(yourselecter).data('wikiTopicId');

Answer (score 0):

First  you must append the html code.Then to change `data Attribute` 
simple change the order

```
 $('#insertHere').html(msg);
 $(msg).find('#submit-problem-phrase-button').attr('data', wikiTopicId);
```

like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  async: false,
  url: contextpath + "/phase/data/getData",
  data: postData,
  success: function(msg) {
    msg = '<div class="row-sml"> <div class="col col-xs-12 text-right plr30 mb8 displayhide"><button type="button"  class="btn btn-light-grey cus-btn mt10 rephrase-btn" id="submit-problem-phrase-button"> Submit</button> </div > ';
    $('#insertHere').html(msg);
    $(msg).find('#submit-problem-phrase-button').attr('data', wikiTopicId);

  },
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    $('.loader02,#overlay-bg,.trans-overlay').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
$(msg).find('#submit-problem-phrase-button').attr('data',wikiTopicId);
```

...will parse the HTML, find the element within that parsed HTML, and add an attribute toit — and then throw all that away. Then this line:

```
$('#insertHere').html(msg);
```

**re**parses the HTML and inserts it.

Instead, insert it, then update:

```
$('#insertHere').html(msg);
$('#submit-problem-phrase-button').attr('data',wikiTopicId);
```

Note that I didn't use `find`. IDs **must** be unique, so we can just use `$("#...")`.

---

Side note: `data` is an invalid HTML attribute name. You can use anything starting with `data-`, but `data`, itself, is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".fa-trash").attr("data-rowid", msg.Sr_No);
```

add the class or id of element for whcih you want to add the attribute and then the entity name